# Boolean condition doesn't work in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm trying to add in my template a simple "s" to a string depending on the number of answers :

The house contains {{nb_results2}} {% if nb_results2 >= 2 %}rooms{% else %}room{% endif %}

{{nb_results2}} appears in my page (it's a str of a count), but whatever the number is, only "room" is displayed.
Is it something related to the string nature of my nb_results variable ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You've given the answer already: it's a **str** of a count. But you are comparing it with an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 'pluralize', this should work even if nb_results2 is a string.

```
The house contains {{ nb_results2 }} room{{ nb_results2|pluralize }}.
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize